# How to unserialize serialized data in php in Flutter?

Tags: php, flutter, serialization

I have some serialized data from php language like this.

```
a: 1: {s: 7: "picture"; s: 13: "Free Shipping";}
```

I want to make meaningful and use this data in Flutter (like json). So I want to use php unserialize method in flutter. I can do this manually, but it can cause minor errors. Is there a method you can suggest for this?

Comment: PHP serialization format is not portable to other languages, unless you create your own parser to parse it, see the internal [code here](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/var_unserializer.re).

I suggest you to use widely used format like JSON, XML, etc.

Comment: In case you cannot change the format, you should use PHP to unserialize it and convert it to another format. Because serialized data may contain state of an object which is only valid in PHP.

Comment: thanks for your reply @ammar-faizi, I guess I'll have to access data manually via string

Comment: And that other format should be JSON, take a look at the json_encode() and json_decode() functions.

Answer (score -2):

i think this can help

```
print_r(unserialize('a: 1: {s: 7: "picture"; s: 13: "Free Shipping";}'));
```

Comment: but currently I am not authorized to make changes to the php code

Comment: This won't work, since the serilaized string is _not_ JSON format.

Comment: That is not JSON format, you cannot use `json_decode` to unserialize it. This is the correct function to do that https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

Comment: sorry people i don't ready this one very well the first time, I've fix the answer 
my bad.